# Maven can't find a compiler on Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, maven, fedora

### Problem:

I've installed a new Fedora system, Maven and Eclipse. I checked out a project and now I'm trying to load all dependencies manually, using the terminal.
Doing `mvn clean install` I get:

```
which: no javac in (/home/user/apache-maven-3.2.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin)
Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.

// ... successfully downloading all dependencies ...

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:48 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-13T19:01:37+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/78M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project featurecrawler: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

### Additional information:

I haven't installed Java additionally, I'm using what already comes with Fedora.
In `/usr/lib/` there are the following folders:

- java
- java-1.5.0
- java-1.6.0
- java-1.7.0
- java-1.8.0
- jvm

Except for `jvm`, all other folders appear to be empty.

`jvm` contains the following folders:

- java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64
- jre-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64 (link to `java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre`)
- jre-1.7.0-openjdk (link to `/etc/alternatives/jre_1.7.0_openjdk`)
- jre-1.7.0 (link to `/etc/alternatives/jre_1.7.0`)
- jre-openjdk (link to `/etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk`)
- jre (link to `/etc/alternatives/jre`)

---

In Eclipse Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs is per default `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64`

---

In `$ vi ~/.bash_profile` I added `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64`.

---

```
which java: /usr/bin/java
```

---

The number of already installed Java version confuses me, I just don't know which one to use. Maybe I need Oracle's Java?

Comment: It looks you don't have installed a JDK. Just try to do `javac -version`?

Comment: @khmarbaise: You are right: `javac: command not found...`

Comment: This means you don't have installed a JDK...so you need to install one to get Maven working. So Maven couldn't find a compiler if you haven't installed one ;-)

Comment: @khmarbaise: I installed it with `su -c "yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk"`, restarted the terminal, tried `javac` command, but got the same error.

Comment: do you have `javac` at directory `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/bin`

Comment: Ok, I had to install `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` rather than `java-1.8.0-openjdk`. Thank you all!

Comment: @khmarbaise: Could you please answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you don't have installed a JDK...so you need to install one to get Maven working.